# TimeSeriesAggregate unwanted behavior

Tags: time-series

Let's take the

```
 lst = {{"2019-09-12 00:01:23",1}, {"2019-09-12 00:01:23", 3}, {"2019-09-12 00:01:24",10}};
```

Assume I want to count events within  1 second.

One way is to use

```
 TemporalData
```

with arguments

```
   Automatic, ValueDimensions->2
```

So,

```
 ts0=TemporalData[lst, Automatic, ValueDimensions-> 2]
```

Now I want to use TimeSeriesAggregate[] to lump events within 1 second window together. Should this be done via ts0["Values"] as follows ?

```
  TimeSeriesAggregate[ts0["Values"],1,f[#]&]
```

If so, what TimeSeriesAggregate does without the user necessarily knowing is that the first two datapoints are lumped together as average. The user didn't specify this ? The user wants to take the Length of those events within the time window.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with `TimeSeriesAggregate`, but maybe the following does what you need? `KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[lst, First -> Last, Total]`

Comment: I think that `ts0` does not behave the way you probably assume it does; using `Automatic` as the second argument in `TemporalData` sets the *time* indexes of the `TemporalData` object automatically while using `ValueDimensions->2` creates a vector process where the first argument of each vector is a *date string*.

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri thank you for looking at it. I dont think I completely misunderstood. But can you be specific in what you think I misunderstood by concrete example ? "vector process" and these terms are non-standard. 

What would I need to do get it to work the way I'd like it ?
I would like to apply a function f  to non-overlapping windows of let's say dt=10, where dt is measured in seconds.

Comment: `lst` understood as time-value pairs is incorrect input for `TemporalData` or `TimeSeries` due to duplicate time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

## Replicating the question

Consider what happens when we define a `TemporalData` object using `tss` (please look at the data section of this answer-`tss` is effectively, equivalent, to the three-point list `lst`; the only difference is that it's made up of *100* observations, this time) and supply the same options as in the question:

```
tds = TemporalData[tss, Automatic, ValueDimensions -> 2];
```

The `Automatic` part in the definition instructs the `TemporalData` object to use zero-based integer time signatures (that's the *default* behavior documented in [TemporalData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) (see the '**Details & Options**' section)). This is evident below: evaluating `tds["Times"]` produces

> ```
> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}
> ```

which is equivalent to `Range[0, 99]`.

The `ValueDimensions -> 2` options, instructs the `TemporalData` object to interpret its input in the first position ie. the `tss` list of date-value pairs as a *list of vectors* (for lack of a better term-please feel free to interject and propose a better one) consisting of two components each. Please note that this is how it's supposed to interpret the `ValueDimensions` option value. Perhaps it will help to take a look at the documentation (see above) at the section '**Options/ValueDimensions**'.

Practically, in the definition above, `tds` is a time series with a time index over consecutive integers (*0*-*99*) and values that are pairs of a *string* (the original time stamp) and a numeric value. Evaluating `tds["Values"]` reports

> ```
> {{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:30.525 PM,69.6447},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:34.525 PM,69.5365},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:36.525 PM,69.4284},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:38.525 PM,69.3207},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:42.525 PM,69.2138},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:43.525 PM,69.1076},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:48.525 PM,69.0023},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:51.525 PM,68.8977},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:54.525 PM,68.7937},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:56.525 PM,68.691},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:57.525 PM,68.5896},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:59.525 PM,68.4902},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.3931},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.2985},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:07.525 PM,68.2075},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:10.525 PM,68.1213},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,68.0414},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,67.9694},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:12.525 PM,67.9072},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:13.525 PM,67.8568},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:15.525 PM,67.8201},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:18.525 PM,67.7996},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:20.525 PM,67.7971},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:23.525 PM,67.8145},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:25.525 PM,67.8531},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:27.525 PM,67.9136},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:30.525 PM,67.9959},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:33.525 PM,68.0995},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.2234},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.3659},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:37.525 PM,68.5253},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:42.525 PM,68.6994},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:44.525 PM,68.8855},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:49.525 PM,69.0801},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:51.525 PM,69.2791},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:56.525 PM,69.4779},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:00.525 PM,69.6719},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,69.8569},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,70.0288},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:05.525 PM,70.1845},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.3209},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.4358},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:13.525 PM,70.528},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:17.525 PM,70.598},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.647},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.6777},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:27.525 PM,70.6929},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6957},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6893},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:31.525 PM,70.677},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:33.525 PM,70.6619},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:34.525 PM,70.6463},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:38.525 PM,70.6323},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:41.525 PM,70.6219},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6161},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6152},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6189},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6263},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:49.525 PM,70.6369},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:54.525 PM,70.6501},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:59.525 PM,70.6655},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.6836},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.7052},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:06.525 PM,70.732},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:08.525 PM,70.7656},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:09.525 PM,70.8078},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:12.525 PM,70.86},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:14.525 PM,70.9225},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:16.525 PM,70.995},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:20.525 PM,71.0761},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:24.525 PM,71.1641},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:28.525 PM,71.2572},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:30.525 PM,71.3535},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:34.525 PM,71.4515},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:37.525 PM,71.55},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:42.525 PM,71.6477},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.7433},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.8358},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:47.525 PM,71.9244},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:52.525 PM,72.0077},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:55.525 PM,72.0842},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:58.525 PM,72.1528},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:02.525 PM,72.2123},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:04.525 PM,72.2625},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:08.525 PM,72.3038},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:09.525 PM,72.3371},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:11.525 PM,72.3639},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:15.525 PM,72.3861},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:20.525 PM,72.405},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:22.525 PM,72.4218},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:27.525 PM,72.4371},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:29.525 PM,72.4508},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:31.525 PM,72.4625},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4716},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4778},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:36.525 PM,72.4815},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4835},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4845},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4849},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:42.525 PM,72.4852}}
> ```

which is-as noted above-a list of string-value pairs. Similarly, evaluating `tds["Paths"]` returns

> ```
> {{{0,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:30.525 PM,69.6447}},{1,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:34.525 PM,69.5365}},{2,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:36.525 PM,69.4284}},{3,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:38.525 PM,69.3207}},{4,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:42.525 PM,69.2138}},{5,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:43.525 PM,69.1076}},{6,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:48.525 PM,69.0023}},{7,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:51.525 PM,68.8977}},{8,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:54.525 PM,68.7937}},{9,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:56.525 PM,68.691}},{10,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:57.525 PM,68.5896}},{11,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:59.525 PM,68.4902}},{12,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.3931}},{13,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.2985}},{14,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:07.525 PM,68.2075}},{15,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:10.525 PM,68.1213}},{16,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,68.0414}},{17,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,67.9694}},{18,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:12.525 PM,67.9072}},{19,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:13.525 PM,67.8568}},{20,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:15.525 PM,67.8201}},{21,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:18.525 PM,67.7996}},{22,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:20.525 PM,67.7971}},{23,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:23.525 PM,67.8145}},{24,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:25.525 PM,67.8531}},{25,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:27.525 PM,67.9136}},{26,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:30.525 PM,67.9959}},{27,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:33.525 PM,68.0995}},{28,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.2234}},{29,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.3659}},{30,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:37.525 PM,68.5253}},{31,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:42.525 PM,68.6994}},{32,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:44.525 PM,68.8855}},{33,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:49.525 PM,69.0801}},{34,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:51.525 PM,69.2791}},{35,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:56.525 PM,69.4779}},{36,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:00.525 PM,69.6719}},{37,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,69.8569}},{38,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,70.0288}},{39,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:05.525 PM,70.1845}},{40,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.3209}},{41,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.4358}},{42,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:13.525 PM,70.528}},{43,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:17.525 PM,70.598}},{44,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.647}},{45,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.6777}},{46,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:27.525 PM,70.6929}},{47,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6957}},{48,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6893}},{49,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:31.525 PM,70.677}},{50,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:33.525 PM,70.6619}},{51,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:34.525 PM,70.6463}},{52,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:38.525 PM,70.6323}},{53,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:41.525 PM,70.6219}},{54,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6161}},{55,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6152}},{56,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6189}},{57,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6263}},{58,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:49.525 PM,70.6369}},{59,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:54.525 PM,70.6501}},{60,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:59.525 PM,70.6655}},{61,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.6836}},{62,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.7052}},{63,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:06.525 PM,70.732}},{64,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:08.525 PM,70.7656}},{65,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:09.525 PM,70.8078}},{66,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:12.525 PM,70.86}},{67,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:14.525 PM,70.9225}},{68,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:16.525 PM,70.995}},{69,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:20.525 PM,71.0761}},{70,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:24.525 PM,71.1641}},{71,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:28.525 PM,71.2572}},{72,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:30.525 PM,71.3535}},{73,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:34.525 PM,71.4515}},{74,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:37.525 PM,71.55}},{75,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:42.525 PM,71.6477}},{76,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.7433}},{77,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.8358}},{78,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:47.525 PM,71.9244}},{79,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:52.525 PM,72.0077}},{80,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:55.525 PM,72.0842}},{81,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:58.525 PM,72.1528}},{82,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:02.525 PM,72.2123}},{83,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:04.525 PM,72.2625}},{84,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:08.525 PM,72.3038}},{85,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:09.525 PM,72.3371}},{86,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:11.525 PM,72.3639}},{87,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:15.525 PM,72.3861}},{88,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:20.525 PM,72.405}},{89,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:22.525 PM,72.4218}},{90,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:27.525 PM,72.4371}},{91,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:29.525 PM,72.4508}},{92,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:31.525 PM,72.4625}},{93,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4716}},{94,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4778}},{95,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:36.525 PM,72.4815}},{96,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4835}},{97,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4845}},{98,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4849}},{99,{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:42.525 PM,72.4852}}}}
> ```

which is the *single* path available to `tss`; note how the `"Values"` of the path are essentially the string-value pairs discussed above.

A `TemporalData` object can host a `number` of possibly different *time paths*. These can be scalar-valued (ie contain a single observation per time instance) or they can be vectors (what we are dealing with here with `ValueDimensions -> 2`). When a `TemporalData` object contains one or more scalar paths, I think that the interpretation favored by the *Documentation* is to consider the object as a collection of different instantiations of the *same* process. When on the other hand, one is handling a vector process (again, I'm using the terms in no rigorous way-please feel free to interject and propose a better terminology) with a single path, the intuition is that the observations are over a '*composite*' object (eg. *position*, *acceleration*, *velocity* of a moving object). In closing, nothing forbids you to encapsulate many paths of a vector process in the `TemporalData` object. I think though that the majority of the time series related built-in functionality of *Mathematica* (or *Wolfram Language*) does not play well with vector valued processes.

The problem with `TimeSeriesAggregate[tds, 1, f[#] &]` as should be expected from the discussion above, is that `1` does not signify a temporal difference of one second *in the context of the underlying series*. Also, the series `tds`-as is the case with `lst`, in the question-is vector valued, with pairs of string-numeric entries, over an integer range, courtesy of the `ValueDimensions` option value used.

## Proposed solution

Define a `TemporalData` object without any options, as in

```
td = TemporalData[ts];
```

Please note that `ts` is provided in the *Data* section of this answer and is essentially the same time series with `tss` used above, only this time the timestamps are not strings but the corresponding `AbsoluteTime` values.

Notice how the data are not regularly sampled (`RegularlySampledQ[td]` evaluates to `False`). This fact alone can introduce artifacts into the analysis if one is not careful. Also note how `MinimumTimeIncrement[td]` evaluates to `1` and `Differences[td["Times"]]` shows the time differences between consecutive observations.

> ```
> {4.,2.,2.,4.,1.,5.,3.,3.,2.,1.,2.,4.,4.,3.,1.,1.,1.,2.,3.,2.,3.,2.,2.,3.,3.,1.,3.,5.,2.,5.,2.,5.,4.,4.,1.,5.,3.,4.,5.,5.,1.,3.,2.,1.,4.,3.,3.,4.,1.,5.,5.,3.,4.,2.,1.,3.,2.,2.,4.,4.,4.,2.,4.,3.,5.,3.,2.,5.,3.,3.,4.,2.,4.,1.,2.,4.,5.,2.,5.,2.,2.,1.,4.,2.,4.}
> ```

Assuming the objective is to bundle together consecutive observations no more than eg *10 seconds* apart, this can be achieved by `TimeSeriesAggregate[td, 10, Mean]` where `Mean` is used as a data operator. Please note how `TimeSeriesAggregate` seems to collect observations that are located in non-overlapping windows of width no more than 10 seconds (in this case). If the objective is instead to bundle together observations whose accumulated time differences is less than eg 10 seconds, then a quick way to do it (and by no means the only one) is to use `reconstruct[td, 10]` from the *Code* section of this answer.

```
DateListPlot[{TimeSeriesAggregate[td,10,Mean],reconstruct[td,10]},PlotLegends->{TimeSeriesAggregate,reconstruct},PlotLabel->Row[{Δt,"=",Quantity[10,"Seconds"]}]]
```

> [image]

Hope some of it helps.

---

## Other auxiliary code

```
(* partition a time series based on the time differences between subsequent observations *)

(* returns an appropriate number of bundles in the original series *)
tsPartnI[dtimes_,dt_]:=Module[{bag,rest,n,take,fold},
  {bag,rest,n}=Fold[
    If[
      #1[[-1]]+#2<=dt,
      {#1[[1]],Join[#1[[2]],{#2}],#1[[-1]]+#2},
      {Join[#1[[1]],{#1[[2]]}],{#2},#2}
     ]&,{{},{},0},dtimes];

  (* deals with cases where the first underlying time difference is greater than dt *)
  If[bag[[1]]=={},take=Rest[bag],take=bag];

  (* deals with trailing overhanging elements *)
  If[Length[rest]>0,fold=Join[take,{rest}],fold=take];

  fold//Map[Length]
 ];

(* partitions the original series according to the appropriate number of bundles *)
tsPartn[y_,bundles_]:=Module[{b},
  b=Fold[
    With[{x=TakeDrop[#1[[-1]],#2]},
      {Join[#1[[1]],{x[[1]]}],x[[-1]]}
     ]&,{{},y},bundles];

  Join[b[[1]],{b[[-1]]}]
 ]

(* reconstruct the bundled series *)
reconstruct[series_,dt_]:=Module[{bundles,times,values},
  bundles=tsPartnI[Differences[series["Times"]],dt];

  values=tsPartn[series["Values"],bundles];
  times=tsPartn[series["Times"],bundles];

  TemporalData[Mean/@values,{times[[All,-1]]}]
 ]
```

## Data sources

```
(* random string date and value pairs *) 
tss = {{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:30.525 PM,69.6447},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:34.525 PM,69.5365},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:36.525 PM,69.4284},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:38.525 PM,69.3207},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:42.525 PM,69.2138},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:43.525 PM,69.1076},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:48.525 PM,69.0023},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:51.525 PM,68.8977},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:54.525 PM,68.7937},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:56.525 PM,68.691},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:57.525 PM,68.5896},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:14:59.525 PM,68.4902},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.3931},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:03.525 PM,68.2985},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:07.525 PM,68.2075},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:10.525 PM,68.1213},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,68.0414},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:11.525 PM,67.9694},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:12.525 PM,67.9072},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:13.525 PM,67.8568},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:15.525 PM,67.8201},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:18.525 PM,67.7996},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:20.525 PM,67.7971},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:23.525 PM,67.8145},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:25.525 PM,67.8531},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:27.525 PM,67.9136},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:30.525 PM,67.9959},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:33.525 PM,68.0995},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.2234},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:34.525 PM,68.3659},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:37.525 PM,68.5253},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:42.525 PM,68.6994},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:44.525 PM,68.8855},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:49.525 PM,69.0801},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:51.525 PM,69.2791},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:15:56.525 PM,69.4779},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:00.525 PM,69.6719},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,69.8569},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:04.525 PM,70.0288},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:05.525 PM,70.1845},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.3209},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:10.525 PM,70.4358},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:13.525 PM,70.528},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:17.525 PM,70.598},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.647},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:22.525 PM,70.6777},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:27.525 PM,70.6929},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6957},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:28.525 PM,70.6893},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:31.525 PM,70.677},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:33.525 PM,70.6619},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:34.525 PM,70.6463},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:38.525 PM,70.6323},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:41.525 PM,70.6219},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6161},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:44.525 PM,70.6152},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6189},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:48.525 PM,70.6263},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:49.525 PM,70.6369},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:54.525 PM,70.6501},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:16:59.525 PM,70.6655},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.6836},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:02.525 PM,70.7052},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:06.525 PM,70.732},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:08.525 PM,70.7656},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:09.525 PM,70.8078},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:12.525 PM,70.86},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:14.525 PM,70.9225},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:16.525 PM,70.995},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:20.525 PM,71.0761},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:24.525 PM,71.1641},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:28.525 PM,71.2572},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:30.525 PM,71.3535},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:34.525 PM,71.4515},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:37.525 PM,71.55},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:42.525 PM,71.6477},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.7433},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:45.525 PM,71.8358},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:47.525 PM,71.9244},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:52.525 PM,72.0077},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:55.525 PM,72.0842},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:17:58.525 PM,72.1528},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:02.525 PM,72.2123},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:04.525 PM,72.2625},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:08.525 PM,72.3038},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:09.525 PM,72.3371},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:11.525 PM,72.3639},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:15.525 PM,72.3861},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:20.525 PM,72.405},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:22.525 PM,72.4218},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:27.525 PM,72.4371},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:29.525 PM,72.4508},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:31.525 PM,72.4625},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4716},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:32.525 PM,72.4778},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:36.525 PM,72.4815},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4835},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4845},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:38.525 PM,72.4849},{Fri, Oct 11 '19-15:18:42.525 PM,72.4852}};

(* same as above with AbsoluteTime[] used on the date string *)
ts = {{3.7798*10^9,69.6447},{3.7798*10^9,69.5365},{3.7798*10^9,69.4284},{3.7798*10^9,69.3207},{3.7798*10^9,69.2138},{3.7798*10^9,69.1076},{3.7798*10^9,69.0023},{3.7798*10^9,68.8977},{3.7798*10^9,68.7937},{3.7798*10^9,68.691},{3.7798*10^9,68.5896},{3.7798*10^9,68.4902},{3.7798*10^9,68.3931},{3.7798*10^9,68.2985},{3.7798*10^9,68.2075},{3.7798*10^9,68.1213},{3.7798*10^9,68.0414},{3.7798*10^9,67.9694},{3.7798*10^9,67.9072},{3.7798*10^9,67.8568},{3.7798*10^9,67.8201},{3.7798*10^9,67.7996},{3.7798*10^9,67.7971},{3.7798*10^9,67.8145},{3.7798*10^9,67.8531},{3.7798*10^9,67.9136},{3.7798*10^9,67.9959},{3.7798*10^9,68.0995},{3.7798*10^9,68.2234},{3.7798*10^9,68.3659},{3.7798*10^9,68.5253},{3.7798*10^9,68.6994},{3.7798*10^9,68.8855},{3.7798*10^9,69.0801},{3.7798*10^9,69.2791},{3.7798*10^9,69.4779},{3.7798*10^9,69.6719},{3.7798*10^9,69.8569},{3.7798*10^9,70.0288},{3.7798*10^9,70.1845},{3.7798*10^9,70.3209},{3.7798*10^9,70.4358},{3.7798*10^9,70.528},{3.7798*10^9,70.598},{3.7798*10^9,70.647},{3.7798*10^9,70.6777},{3.7798*10^9,70.6929},{3.7798*10^9,70.6957},{3.7798*10^9,70.6893},{3.7798*10^9,70.677},{3.7798*10^9,70.6619},{3.7798*10^9,70.6463},{3.7798*10^9,70.6323},{3.7798*10^9,70.6219},{3.7798*10^9,70.6161},{3.7798*10^9,70.6152},{3.7798*10^9,70.6189},{3.7798*10^9,70.6263},{3.7798*10^9,70.6369},{3.7798*10^9,70.6501},{3.7798*10^9,70.6655},{3.7798*10^9,70.6836},{3.7798*10^9,70.7052},{3.7798*10^9,70.732},{3.7798*10^9,70.7656},{3.7798*10^9,70.8078},{3.7798*10^9,70.86},{3.7798*10^9,70.9225},{3.7798*10^9,70.995},{3.7798*10^9,71.0761},{3.7798*10^9,71.1641},{3.7798*10^9,71.2572},{3.7798*10^9,71.3535},{3.7798*10^9,71.4515},{3.7798*10^9,71.55},{3.7798*10^9,71.6477},{3.7798*10^9,71.7433},{3.7798*10^9,71.8358},{3.7798*10^9,71.9244},{3.7798*10^9,72.0077},{3.7798*10^9,72.0842},{3.7798*10^9,72.1528},{3.7798*10^9,72.2123},{3.7798*10^9,72.2625},{3.7798*10^9,72.3038},{3.7798*10^9,72.3371},{3.7798*10^9,72.3639},{3.7798*10^9,72.3861},{3.7798*10^9,72.405},{3.7798*10^9,72.4218},{3.7798*10^9,72.4371},{3.7798*10^9,72.4508},{3.7798*10^9,72.4625},{3.7798*10^9,72.4716},{3.7798*10^9,72.4778},{3.7798*10^9,72.4815},{3.7798*10^9,72.4835},{3.7798*10^9,72.4845},{3.7798*10^9,72.4849},{3.7797959225251158*10^9,72.4852}};

(* date and time spec used to translate the date and time string in tss into the first ts component *)
(* code used: Map[DateString[#, dtspec] &] *)
dtspec = {"DayNameShort", ",", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "'", "YearShort", "-", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond", " ", "AMPM"};
```